# VIDEOJS: ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, video.js, typescript-typings

I recently discovered the videojs-thumbnails plugin for video.js and I want to implement it to my angular component, however, I keep receiving this error of

`VIDEOJS: ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at Function.updateThumbnailTime`

I've implemented videojs-thumbnails.js via

```
declare var thumbnails: any;
```

I've also ensured that videojs-thumbnails was imported to the .angular-clic.json as

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.css",
    "../node_modules/videojs-resolution-switcher/lib/videojs-resolution-switcher.css",
    "../node_modules/videojs-thumbnails/dist/browser/videojs-thumbnails.css",
    "styles.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/video.js/dist/video.js",
    "../node_modules/videojs-resolution-switcher/lib/videojs-resolution-switcher.js",
    "../node_modules/videojs-thumbnails/dist/browser/videojs-thumbnails.js"
```

Through the videojs-thumbnails.js I keep returning the error of

```
VIDEOJS: ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at Function.updateThumbnailTime
```

Here is what the full component looks like

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

interface VideoJSStatic {
  (id: any, options?: any, ready?: () => void): any;
}

declare var videojs:VideoJSStatic;
declare var videoJsResolutionSwitcher: any;
declare var thumbnails: any;

@Component({
 selector: 'videojs',

  template:`
  <video *ngIf="url" id="video_{{idx}}"
     class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered vjs-16-9"
     controls preload="auto"  width="640" height="264">
  </video>
  `,
})

export class VideoJsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  // reference to the element itself, we use this to access events and methods
  private _elementRef: ElementRef

  // index to create unique ID for component
  @Input() idx: string;

  // video asset url
  @Input() url: any;

  //Video Resolution
  @Input() private options: any = {};
  @Input() private sources: Array<string> = new Array<string>();

  // declare player var
  private player: any; 

  // constructor initializes our declared vars
  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.url = false;
    this.player = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngOnDestroy(){}

 // use ngAfterViewInit to make sure we initialize the videojs element
  // after the component template itself has been rendered
  ngAfterViewInit() {

    //Trial for Video Resoultion
    this.options.plugins = {
      videoJsResolutionSwitcher: {
          default: 'low',
          dynamicLabel: true
      },
    }; 

    // ID with which to access the template's video element
    let el = 'video_' + this.idx;

    // setup the player via the unique element ID
    this.player = videojs(document.getElementById(el),this.options, function() {

      this.updateSrc([
        {
          src: 'http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4',
          type: 'video/mp4',
          label: '1080p'
        },
        {
          src: 'http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4',
          type: 'video/mp4',
          label: '720p'
        },
        {
          src: 'http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4',
          type: 'video/mp4',
          label: '480p'
        },
        {
          src: 'http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4',
          type: 'video/mp4',
          label: '240p'
        }
      ])
      this.on('resolutionchange', function(){
        console.info('Source changed to %s', this.src())
      });

      //Videojs Thumbnails
      this.thumbnails({
        0: {
          src: 'http://example.com/thumbnail1.png',
          width: '120px'
        },
        5: {
          src: 'http://example.com/thumbnail2.png'
        }
      });

      // Store the video object
      var myPlayer = this, id = myPlayer.id();

      // Make up an aspect ratio
      var aspectRatio = 264/640;

      // internal method to handle a window resize event to adjust the video player
      function resizeVideoJS(){
        var width = document.getElementById(id).parentElement.offsetWidth;
        myPlayer.width(width);
        myPlayer.height( width * aspectRatio );
      }

      // Initialize resizeVideoJS()
      resizeVideoJS();

      // Then on resize call resizeVideoJS()
      window.onresize = resizeVideoJS;

    });
  } 
}
```

I know that the library has been imported because if I place

`import '../../../node_modules/videojs-thumbnails/dist/browser/videojs-thumbnails.js'`

into the component,
I get a return error:

`VIDEOJS: WARN: A plugin named "thumbnails" already exists. You may want to avoid re-registering plugins`
I've also tried importing it via `import * as thumbnails from 'videojs-thumbnails';`

Being relatively new to the Angular environment, I've tried multiple importation methods for this library, but they all result in the same thing. What I'm not understanding is that a previous third party plugin called videoJsResolutionSwitcher was imported the same way and I was able to call the updateSrc method without any errors.

Also, my version of video.js is 6.7.3, videojs-resolution-switcher at 0.4.3 and videojs-thumbnails is at version 1.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is embarrassing, The problem to begin with was that I was using a different package than what I thought I had downloaded, and thus used the wrong syntax. The solution was I was using properties that didn't exist with this library. The right way to use the .thumbnails() method is by using

```
this.thumbnails(
  {
    // width of the single sprite clip 
    width: 100,
    // url to sprite image 
    spriteUrl: "//path/to/sprite.jpg",
    // how often to change thumbnail on timeline ( ex. every 2sec ) 
    stepTime: 2,
  }
);
```

I thought I was using Brightcove's version of videojs-thumbnails. Instead I was using a package from npm which was written by someone else but uses the same name unfortunately and not explicitly stated that it's much different.
Furthermore, I ended up using a different library altogether that uses webVTT files and sprites instead.